# how to save data from data grid view to multiple table in vb.net windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

i am working on vb.net windows form application ,,i have a data gridview,,that is loading data from two table..my data grid view something like this:[image]

I have two tables `1->CompanyMaster_tbl` in this having Two fields . `Cid and CompanyName`,

> Cid is the primary key of this table

2->`DepartmentMaster_tbl` in this having 4 fields. `dtid,dtname,dtphon,dtmail,Cid`.

> dtid is the primary key,and Cid is the foreign key

while clicking save button i want save the data in both table.
in this datagrid view comapny name is loading from CompanyMaster_tbl
remaining all loading from  DepartmentMaster_tbl

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is going wrong? What exactly do you not understand? Please elaborate or it is hard to answer.

Comment: Create tow inserts string for each table and loop throw your grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this :

```
        Dim sqlInsertT1 As String = ""
        Dim sqlInsertT2 As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 1
            sqlInsertT1 &= " Insert Into table1(Cid , CompanyName) Values (" & gv.Rows(i).Cells("Cid").Value & ",'" & gv.Rows(i).Cells("CompanyName").Value & "');"
            sqlInsertT2 &= " Insert Into table2(dtid,dtname,dtphon,dtmail,Cid) Values (" & gv.Rows(i).Cells("dtid").Value & " " & _
                ",'" & gv.Rows(i).Cells("dtname").Value & "','" & gv.Rows(i).Cells("dtphon").Value & "','" & gv.Rows(i).Cells("dtmail").Value & "'," & gv.Rows(i).Cells("Cid").Value & ");"
        Next

       'Execute the to string command. 
       'TO DO
```

Comment: then how you want to insert with out them? , you can read them to your DataGridView and set column visible to false and use them only when insert.

Comment: Did you try it? Tell me the results.